# Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?

Tags: c++, portability, turbo-c++, c++-faq, implementation-defined-behavior

I posted a question with my code whose only `#include` directive was the following:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

My teacher told me to do this, but in the comments section I was informed that I shouldn't.

Why?

Comment: Huh. I should have known there would be an include version of `using namespace std;` out there somewhere.

Comment: why does this header even exist? surely none of the standard includes actually include this, since it would bring in lots of junk? and if its not included by any of the public includes... then why is it shipped in the distribution?

Comment: @ChrisBeck: It's an implementation detail. It's not part of the "public API" or meant for use. But it still has to be shipped otherwise nothing would work. The standard includes may not use it individually but it's there for use in precompiled headers. See the comment at the top, which says: _"This is an implementation file for a precompiled header."_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you aren’t supposed to use it yourself, how does its existence help with PCH? Or is gcc smart enough to automatically switch over to it for PCH purposes in some circumstances?

Comment: @DanielH: Good question. Um, I don't know really, but that was probably what I was thinking yeah. Might be a good question in its own right.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"It's not part of the "public API" or meant for use."_ Entirely wrong, it's intended for public use, as a precompiled header. Libstdc++ (pre)compiles and installs a precompiled version of that header, so if you include it then G++ will actually include `bits/stdc++.h.gch` instead, the precompiled version. It exists because it has to exist so that the precompiled version of it can be generated.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The public API of the standard library, I mean; not of libstdc++. The people using it on Stack Overflow every day (and in their projects) are not using it for the reason, or in the use case, that you're talking about. Sure, my comment could have been worded more accurately, though note that I _did_ point out its use for precompiled headers. Feel free to write a competing answer.

Comment: Geeksforgeeks is spreading this. It has answers for technical interview coding rounds. Here is the reason. When you are solving a problem and writing code, you may start with a vector but then you think that map would be better. So everytime you change your mind, you have to update headers. One might miss that in rush. So it's a helpful here. Use should be discouraged in general programming though.

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore if you're unsure of which datatype to use while writing your code, then you haven't thought your solution out well enough yet. Go back to pencil and paper. Or have a template where all the datatypes you might need are included and renamed already. IDK any self-respecting competitive programmer who would include `<bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: If a standards meeting ever falls on 1st April. it might be fun to propose an "include everything" header.  With this exact name, of course, "because it's already in common use" ...

Comment: I think a better proposal is for the gcc team to rename this header file to some different name, in each and every release of gcc/g++, so as to deliberately break any non-gcc source code that tries to access it.  It's the only way to stop the madness :)

Comment: @TobySpeight too late: [LWG 1002](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1002) and [N2905](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2905.pdf).

Answer (score 518, accepted):

Including `<bits/stdc++.h>` appears to be an increasingly common thing to see on Stack Overflow, perhaps something newly added to a national curriculum in the current academic year.

I imagine the advantages are vaguely given thus:

- You only need write one `#include` line.
- You do not need to look up which standard header everything is in.

Unfortunately, this is a lazy hack, naming a GCC internal header directly instead of individual standard headers like `<string>`, `<iostream>` and `<vector>`. It ruins portability and fosters terrible habits.

The disadvantages include:

- It will probably only work on that compiler.
- You have no idea what it'll do when you use it, because its contents are not set by a standard.
- Even just upgrading your compiler to its own next version may break your program.
- Every single standard header must be parsed and compiled along with your source code, which is slow and results in a bulky executable under certain compilation settings.

**Don't do it!**

---

More information:

- [#include <bits/stdc++.h> with visual studio does not compile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25337300/560648)
- [How does #include <bits/stdc++.h> work in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25311052/560648)

Example of why Quora is bad:

- [Is it good practice to use #include <bits/stdc++.h> in programming contests instead of listing a lot of includes?](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-good-practice-to-use-include-bits-stdc++-h-in-programming-contests-instead-of-listing-a-lot-of-includes)

Comment: "perhaps something newly added to a national curriculum in the current academic year" Blind leading the blind :(

Comment: Under certain compilation settings, however, the use of precompiled headers will reduce compilation time. Also, with standard out-of-the-box settings, I just compiled a trivial program with and without `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and the difference in the size of the EXE file was 91 KB with, 89 KB without.

Comment: Just came here through a wormhole in another question, very good. What makes this teaching habit worse is that it is usually followed by a direct `using namesapce std;`. Just two lines in and virtually every nice identifier is used. Incredibly frustrating to see it being taught.

Comment: About the quora example, it might have shifted with time. I've visited the page today and both pros and cons of <bits/stdc++.h> where listed in the specific context of online programming contests. I find their conclusion ok-ish.

Comment: The fourth bulletpoint is advantageous if precompiled headers are in use. [See here for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726155/whats-the-use-for-stdafx-h-in-visual-studio), this code is basically the gcc version of `#include "stdafx.h"`

Comment: @M.M: Not really - just because you're precompiling headers doesn't mean you need to precompile _every_ header

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: 2KiB is *a lot* of code, data, symbol information, etc., when trying to determine its effect. Do you understand everything that is being added? For your compiler? The current release? All releases in between? All future releases? If you need to decide between convenience and correctness, there is only a single valid option.

Comment: Hopefully not a curriculum but rather just a cargo-cult spread across 'contest' websites or something... although sadly nothing would surprise me either way.

Comment: An heaven forbid you are using the pre-compiled headers option with it. Take a look at the size of the .pch file generated by VS under one of your repos/Debug (or Release) directories, They can be tens to hundreds of megabyes.

Comment: Devil's advocate. While all this is certainly true for professional code, you might make an argument that the include is acceptable for people using C++ to learn programming for the first time -- it lets them concentrate on their own code, and makes the teacher's grading job easier.  The disadvantages (except your second bullet point to some extent) go away in a pedagogical situation.  Frankly, the `using namespace std` makes me cringe more than the include.

Comment: Lets have a new take on this please. All the points mentioned above are all very valid...however, shouldn't we fix all of them so we "can" actually just have 1 include line? Shouldn't our compiler do all the work to find the right header and include it if we wish?

Comment: Updated link [C++ Standard - 16.5.1.2 Headers](http://eel.is/c++draft/headers)

Comment: @SujayPhadke> yes, the compiler should guess what the developer has in mind. Because of course there is only one function in the world named `distance`, the word `vector` certainly has no meaning outside of containers, … You're right a tool should help with this. But that's not a job for the compiler, that's the job of the IDE (and some of them indeed do it).

Comment: @spectras there's no need of sarcasm. There is no need to guess. By default the compiler just needs to have defaults configured. If you decide to change it for your purpose you can do it. By why should the 1000s of people have to keep writing this for their default use when 1 person changes the default behavior?

Comment: @SujayPhadke finding things is simply not the job of the compiler. If something is not defined, it's not defined. Simple, clean, consistent, reliable, reproducible. I agree, having such things automated is great, and in fact many IDEs have this feature (bonus: it works for all libraries, not just the std one). There is no reason to introduce inconsistencies in the language and break design rules in the toolchain.

Comment: Actually, GCC now produces pretty good warnings suggesting missing includes (although it does choose fairly arbitrary spots to recommend them - breaking the sorting order in my programs!)

Comment: `Every single standard header must be parsed and compiled along with your source code, which is slow`. How slow? I did a quick "hello world" test and [posted the results here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71863759/4561887).

Answer (score 118):

Why? Because it is used as if it were supposed to be a C++ standard header, but no standard mentions it. So your code is non-portable by construction. You won't find any documentation for it on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com). So it might as well not exist. It's a figment of someone's imagination :)

I have discovered - to my horror and disbelief - that there is a well-known tutorial site where **every C++ example seems to include this header**. The world is mad. That's the proof.

---

*To anyone writing such "tutorials"*

Please stop using this header. Forget about it. Don't propagate this insanity. If you're unwilling to understand why doing this is **Wrong**, take my word for it. I'm not OK being treated as a figure of authority on anything at all, and I'm probably full of it half the time, but I'll make an exception in this one case only. I claim that I know what I'm talking about here. Take me on my word. I implore you.

P.S. I can well imagine the abominable "teaching standard" where this wicked idea might have taken place, and the circumstances that led to it. Just because there seemed to be a practical need for it doesn't make it acceptable - not even in retrospect.

P.P.S. No, there was no practical need for it. There aren't that many C++ standard headers, and they are well documented. If you teach, you're doing your students a disservice by adding such "magic". Producing programmers with a magical mindset is the last thing we want. If you need to offer students a subset of C++ to make their life easier, just produce a handout with the short list of headers applicable to the course you teach, and with concise documentation for the library constructs you expect the students to use.

Comment: That well known site is that the one where every C++ example looks like a C program?

Comment: He is talking about GeeksForGeeks

Comment: It will be fun when that header is included, along with `using namespace std;`.  Then simple things like a user-defined  [gcd](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd), [swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) or variable named [data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data) will act strangely or not compile at all, leaving the coder scratching their head as to what the issue could be.

Comment: I'm talking about the prototypical "well known site". There are, unfortunately, very many of them. And they all invariably look like blind leading the blind :(

Answer (score 88):

There's a Stack Exchange site called [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). The *programming puzzles* on that site fit this definition of [puzzle](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/puzzle):

> a toy, problem, or other contrivance designed to amuse by presenting difficulties to be solved by ingenuity or patient effort.

They are designed to amuse, and not in the way that a working programmer might be amused by a real-world problem encountered in their daily work.

[Code Golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) is "a type of recreational computer programming competition in which participants strive to achieve the shortest possible source code that implements a certain algorithm." In the answers on the PP&CG site, you'll see people specify the number of bytes in their answers. When they find a way to shave off a few bytes, they'll strike out the original number and record the new one.

As you might expect, code golfing rewards extreme programming language abuse. One-letter variable names. No whitespace. Creative use of library functions. Undocumented features. Nonstandard programming practices. Appalling hacks.

If a programmer submitted a pull request at work containing golf-style code, it would be rejected. Their co-workers would laugh at them. Their manager would drop by their desk for a chat. Even so, programmers amuse themselves by submitting answers to PP&CG.

What does this have to do with `stdc++.h`? As others have pointed out, using it is lazy. It's non-portable, so you don't know if it will work on your compiler or the next version of your compiler. It fosters bad habits. It's non-standard, so your program's behavior may differ from what you expect. It may increase compile time and executable size.

These are all valid and correct objections. So why would anyone use this monstrosity?

It turns out that some people like *programming puzzles* without the *code golf*. They get together and compete at events like ACM-ICPC, Google Code Jam, and Facebook Hacker Cup, or on sites like Topcoder and Codeforces. Their rank is based on program correctness, execution speed, and how fast they submit a solution. To maximize execution speed, many participants use C++. To maximize coding speed, some of them use `stdc++.h`.

Is this is a good idea? Let's check the list of disadvantages. Portability? It doesn't matter since these coding events use a specific compiler version that contestants know in advance. Standards compliance? Not relevant for a block of code whose useful life is less than one hour. Compile time and executable size? These aren't part of the contest's scoring rubric.

So we're left with bad habits. This is a valid objection. By using this header file, contestants are avoiding the chance to learn which standard header file defines the functionality they're using in their program. When they're writing real-world code (and not using `stdc++.h`) they'll have to spend time looking up this information, which means they'll be less productive. That's the downside of practicing with `stdc++.h`.

This raises the question of why it's worth taking part in competitive programming at all if it encourages bad habits like using `stdc++.h` and violating other coding standards. One answer is that people do it for the same reason they post programs on PP&CG: some programmers find it enjoyable to use their coding skills in a game-like context.

So the question of whether to use `stdc++.h` comes down to whether the coding speed benefits in a programming contest outweigh the bad habits that one might develop by using it.

This question asks: "Why should I not #include `<bits/stdc++.h>`?" I realize that it was asked and answered to make a point, and the accepted answer is intended to be the One True Answer to this question. But the question isn't "Why should I not #include `<bits/stdc++.h>` in production code?" Therefore, I think it's reasonable to consider other scenarios where the answer may be different.

Comment: I've upvoted already, but it might be worth pointing out that "for fun" is a good reason to take part in competitive programming.  On the other hand "to impress a potential employers" is not - it will actively *harm* your case with me.

Comment: @MartinBonner I know some hiring managers see competitive programming experience as a red flag. But as long as top software companies use CP-style problems in their interviews and run programming contests to find new recruits, CP will continue to be popular among aspiring developers.

Comment: @RedGreenCode I am not a manager (thank $DEITY), but I sometimes have influence on hireing desitions. And I *definitely* see any reference to "competitive programming" as a *huge* red flag - *not* an advantage.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If technical interviewers at your company use algorithmic puzzles in their interviews (as many do), that gives candidates with competitive programming experience an advantage. Maybe the rational choice for candidates is to participate in CP but avoid mentioning it on their resume/CV.

Comment: While it's true that this header can find use in some competitive programming, it's not quite where it came from. It came from a classroom. And whoever taught in that classroom had enough influence to pollute - via cascade that followed - tens if not hundreds of thousands of students (by educating the teachers and peers who then, unwittingly, had been spreading that disease). And now those students are also writing tutorials in a go-to-place for tutorials. I just want to cry in a corner. Competitive programming sites should just have a **regex to reject any nonstandard header**.

Comment: @RedGreenCode Why is competitive programming a red flag?? It is better than someone who has no programming experience....

Comment: @YunfeiChen Some people believe it encourages bad habits (like using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` or writing unreadable code) that the candidate would need to un-learn on the job. Having zero programming experience is also a red flag, but that's why we have interviews.

Comment: @RedGreenCode When I say zero coding experience I mean people who never worked in a programming job before, most university graduates have not worked in coding before. So they have nothing except for a degree certificate..... Hmm also why does coding competitions not care about effieciency I thought that was the whole point of the competition??

Comment: @YunfeiChen Coding competition scores are based on correctness, runtime speed, and coding speed (submission time). Using `bits/stdc++.h` only affects compilation speed and executable size, so it doesn't affect contest results.

Comment: @YunfeiChen> they also do not care (or even discourage) a lot of things that are very important for professional code. Readability, reusability, testability (of pieces), the ability to build upon existing wheels rather than reinventing it, …

Comment: @spectras well for reability, there's a reason why it is called coding golf, and all three of those factors are very subjective, this is no objective metric to measuring those so it should not be include as part of the criteria....

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica The idea that a mention of CP results on a cv - demonstrating related problem solving skills and active enthusiasm - is a __*negative*__ is simply madness. Coding style and good use of architecture, teamwork, etc. are all essential, but an applicant shouldn't have to tick all of those boxes at each dot point of the cv.

Answer (score 28):

From N4606, Working Draft, Standard for Programming Language C++ :

> 17.6.1.2 Headers [headers]
>
> 1. Each element of the C++ standard library is declared or defined (as appropriate) in a header.
> 2. The C++ standard library provides 61 C++ library headers, as shown in Table 14.
>
> Table 14 — C++ library headers
>
> ```
> <algorithm> <future> <numeric> <strstream>
> <any> <initializer_list> <optional> <system_error>
> <array> <iomanip> <ostream> <thread>
> <atomic> <ios> <queue> <tuple>
> <bitset> <iosfwd> <random> <type_traits>
> <chrono> <iostream> <ratio> <typeindex>
> <codecvt> <istream> <regex> <typeinfo>
> <complex> <iterator> <scoped_allocator> <unordered_map>
> <condition_variable> <limits> <set> <unordered_set>
> <deque> <list> <shared_mutex> <utility>
> <exception> <locale> <sstream> <valarray>
> <execution> <map> <stack> <variant>
> <filesystem> <memory> <stdexcept> <vector>
> <forward_list> <memory_resorce> <streambuf>
> <fstream> <mutex> <string>
> <functional> <new> <string_view>
> ```

There's no <bits/stdc++.h> there. This is not surprising, since <bits/...> headers are  implementation detail, and usually carry a warning:

> - This is an internal header file, included by other library headers.
> - Do not attempt to use it directly.

<bits/stdc++.h> also carries a warning:

> - This is an implementation file for a precompiled header.

Answer (score 10):

*I at least like seeing a list of all headers one can include, and which version of C++ they pertain to, by looking at this header file. It is really useful in that regard.*

### How bad is including `<bits/stdc++.h>`, really?

I wanted to see some real data--some numbers to compare *compile time* and *binary executable size*. So, here is a quick "hello world" comparison test.

Note: to learn *where* is the `<bits/stdc++.h>` header file, and *what* is in it, jump straight down to the section at the bottom titled "Where and what is `<bits/stdc++.h>`?".

### Summary:

**Including the `<bits/stdc++.h>` "include all headers" header is easy, but comparatively slow to compile.**

Including the `<bits/stdc++.h>` header file works fine with the GCC/g++ compiler (and presumably the [LLVM Clang compiler](https://clang.llvm.org/) too, since they aim to be GCC-compatible), and

1. makes *no difference on binary executable size*, but
2. it takes up to **4x longer to compile!**

### My testing

Here is a sample C++ program:

[**include_bits_stdc++.cpp**:](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/include_bits_stdc%2B%2B.cpp)

```cpp
// We will test including this header vs NOT including this header
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#include <iostream>  // For `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::endl`, etc.

int main()
{
    printf("Hello ");
    std::cout << "world!\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some build and run commands:

```bash
# make a bin directory
mkdir -p bin

# compile, timing how long it takes
time g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c++17 include_bits_stdc++.cpp -o bin/a

# check binary executable size
size bin/a

# run
bin/a
```

### WithOUT `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` at the top

If I run the "compile" command above with the code as-is, here are 10 compile times I see:

```
real    0m0.362s
real    0m0.372s
real    0m0.502s
real    0m0.383s
real    0m0.367s
real    0m0.283s
real    0m0.294s
real    0m0.281s
real    0m0.292s
real    0m0.276s
```

**Average compile time:** `(0.362 + 0.372 + 0.502 + 0.383 + 0.367 + 0.283 + 0.294 + 0.281 + 0.292 + 0.276)/10` = **`0.3412` seconds**.

`size bin/a` shows:

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
2142     656     280    3078     c06 bin/a
```

### WITH `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` at the top

10 compile times:

```
real    0m1.398s
real    0m1.006s
real    0m0.952s
real    0m1.331s
real    0m1.549s
real    0m1.454s
real    0m1.417s
real    0m1.541s
real    0m1.546s
real    0m1.558s
```

**Average compile time:** `(1.398 + 1.006 + 0.952 + 1.331 + 1.549 + 1.454 + 1.417 + 1.541 + 1.546 + 1.558)/10` = **`1.3752` seconds**.

`size bin/a` shows:

```
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
2142     656     280    3078     c06 bin/a
```

### Conclusions

So, including the header works fine with the gcc/g++ compiler, and makes *no difference on binary executable size*, but it takes 1.3752 sec / 0.3412 sec = **4x longer to compile!**

### Where and what is `<bits/stdc++.h>`?

#### Summary

The `<bits/stdc++.h>` header file is included as part of the gcc/g++ compiler.

You can find it on your Linux (ex: Ubuntu) system with this command:

```bash
find /usr/include -ipath "*bits/stdc++.h*"
```

The above command is almost instant. But, if it doesn't find anything, you can search your *entire* file system like this, which will take *much* longer:

```bash
# Option 1: showing read permissions errors
find / -ipath "*bits/stdc++.h*"

# Option 2 (preferred): hiding read permissions (stderr, file descriptor 2)
# errors
find / -ipath "*bits/stdc++.h*" 2>/dev/null
```

If on Linux Ubuntu, `<bits/stdc++.h>` will be located on your local system at:

1. On Ubuntu 18.04, with GCC 8: `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8/bits/stdc++.h`
2. On Ubuntu 22.04, with GCC 11: `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/stdc++.h`

You can view the file in the gcc source code directly online here: [gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/precompiled/stdc%2B%2B.h)

*I at least like seeing a list of all headers one can include, and which version of C++ they pertain to, by looking at that header file. It is really useful in that regard.*

#### Details

If you open the code above in an IDE with a great indexer, such as Eclipse (which has the best indexer I've ever found; it indexes *far better* than MS VSCode), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on the `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` line, it will jump straight to that header file on your system! On Linux Ubuntu, it jumps straight to this path and opens this file: `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8/bits/stdc++.h`.

You can view the latest version of this file in the gcc source code directly, here: [gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/precompiled/stdc%2B%2B.h). **It is simply a header file which *includes all other header files!*** This is really useful and insightful to just look at all header files in one place to get a feel for what they are and what they include! And again, in Eclipse, you can easily <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on each included header file to jump right to its source code implementation.

Here is the full, latest `<bits/stdc++.h>` header file included with the gcc compiler. You can always copy and paste this content and create this file yourself if you want to include it in your own personal project or use it with another compiler.

**[gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/precompiled/stdc++.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/precompiled/stdc%2B%2B.h):**

```cpp
// C++ includes used for precompiling -*- C++ -*-

// Copyright (C) 2003-2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
//
// This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library.  This library is free
// software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
// terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
// Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
// any later version.

// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.

// Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
// permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
// 3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
// a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
// see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see
// <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/** @file stdc++.h
 *  This is an implementation file for a precompiled header.
 */

// 17.4.1.2 Headers

// C
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_NO_ASSERT
#include <cassert>
#endif
#include <cctype>
#include <cfloat>
#include <ciso646>
#include <climits>
#include <csetjmp>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <cstdint>
#endif

// C++
// #include <bitset>
// #include <complex>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include <new>
#include <numeric>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <ratio>
#include <scoped_allocator>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>
#endif

#if __cplusplus >= 201402L
#endif

#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
#include <any>
// #include <execution>
#include <optional>
#include <variant>
#include <string_view>
#endif

#if __cplusplus >= 202002L
#include <bit>
#include <compare>
#include <concepts>
#include <numbers>
#include <ranges>
#include <span>
#include <source_location>
#include <version>
#endif

#if __cplusplus > 202002L
#include <expected>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#if __cpp_impl_coroutine
# include <coroutine>
#endif
#endif

#if _GLIBCXX_HOSTED
// C
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_NO_ASSERT
#include <cassert>
#endif
#include <cctype>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cfloat>
#include <ciso646>
#include <climits>
#include <clocale>
#include <cmath>
#include <csetjmp>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <cwchar>
#include <cwctype>

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <ccomplex>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cstdalign>
#include <cstdbool>
#include <cstdint>
#include <ctgmath>
#include <cuchar>
#endif

// C++
#include <complex>
#include <deque>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <iterator>
#include <limits>
#include <list>
#include <locale>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <new>
#include <numeric>
#include <ostream>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>
#include <codecvt>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <forward_list>
#include <future>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include <ratio>
#include <regex>
#include <scoped_allocator>
#include <system_error>
#include <thread>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeindex>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#endif

#if __cplusplus >= 201402L
#include <shared_mutex>
#endif

#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
#include <any>
#include <charconv>
// #include <execution>
#include <filesystem>
#include <optional>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <variant>
#endif

#if __cplusplus >= 202002L
#include <barrier>
#include <bit>
#include <compare>
#include <concepts>
#include <format>
#include <latch>
#include <numbers>
#include <ranges>
#include <span>
#include <stop_token>
#include <semaphore>
#include <source_location>
#include <syncstream>
#include <version>
#endif

#if __cplusplus > 202002L
#include <expected>
#include <generator>
#include <print>
#include <spanstream>
#if __has_include(<stacktrace>)
# include <stacktrace>
#endif
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdfloat>
#endif

#if __cplusplus > 202302L
#include <text_encoding>
#endif

#endif // HOSTED
```

### See also

1. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitsstdc-h-c/

   - this article plagiarizes from Stack Overflow, though; see my comment here:
     [How does #include <bits/stdc++.h> work in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311011/how-does-include-bits-stdc-h-work-in-c/33764128#comment126990806_33764128)
2. [my Questions & Answers] learn what `text`, `data`, `bss`, and `dec` mean in the `size` output:

   1. [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange: How do I find out at compile time how much of an STM32's Flash memory and dynamic memory (SRAM) is used up?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/363931/26234)
   2. [Convert binutils `size` output from "sysv" format (`size --format=sysv my_executable`) to "berkeley" format (`size --format=berkeley my_executable`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64073080/4561887)

Comment: Because the file is GPL licensed, you should be careful about copying it for your own project.  It might open you to legal liabilities that could be very unfortunate for you and your employer.

Comment: "If on Linux, it will be located on your local system at ... " - not necessarily, it depends on where you got your gcc, how it was packaged, etc. On my system it's at a completely different path from the one you show.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, answer updated to specify Ubuntu. Where is it located on your system, and which version of Linux do you have?

Comment: I have 141 different copies of it. I don't think giving you the paths will be useful. I don't think stating the path in your answer is really useful either (e.g. you forgot to say Ubuntu amd64). The precise location isn't important, gcc knows where to find it.

Answer (score 7):

The reason we do not use:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

is because of effiency.
Let me make an analogy:
For those of you who know Java:
If you asked your instructor if the following was a good idea, unless they are a bad instructor they would say no:

```
import java.*.*
```

The #include... thing does the same thing basically... That's not the only reason not to use it, but it is one of the major reasons not to use it.
For a real life analogy:
Imagine you had a library and you wanted to borrow a couple of books from the library, would you relocate the entire library next to your house?? It would be expensive and ineffiecient. If you only need 5 books, well then only take out 5... Not the whole library.....

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

Looks convienent to the program look I only need to type one include statement and it works, same thing with moving a whole library, look I only need to move one whole library instead of 5 books, one by one. Looks convienent to you that is, for the person who actually has to do the moving?? Not so much, and guess what in C++ the person doing the moving will be your computer... The computer will not enjoy moving the entire library for every source file you write :).....

Comment: This is almost certainly the underlying reason why nobody has seriously proposed a  Standard "include everything" header.  So there's a plausible claim to call it "_the_ reason" we don't use it.

Comment: But computers are very fast , these things doesn't effect that much , it will done in like milliseconds, MISERY will waste human time instead.

Comment: @UNREAL you have never worked on a large scale project have you? It adds up very quickly when you have many files.

Comment: What if I have not  a large scale project, Can I use bits/stdc++.h .

Comment: @UNREAL Thats up to you, but just note it is non standard and not portable, meaning you will run into compatiability issues later on.

Comment: @UNREAL My experience is including bits/stdc++.h without having precompiled headers set up correctly increases the amount to time spent compiling by close to an order of magnitude (better disk IO and no antivirus will help a lot here). So if your build time for a single small file increase from half a second to five seconds, you'll probably shoot past the amount of time you saved typing in one header instead of four or five headers in about 3 compiles. In other words if your program works right the first or second time, you win. After that you start to lose.

Comment: @user4581301 that is assuming the IDE you use doesnt auto import headers for you, which is very common for IDEs these days.

Comment: Yes IDE  our angel , nothing to worry.

Comment: The comparison is very wrong, as is the answer:
In Java `import java.*.*` is valid and well-defined, in C++ `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` IS NOT as that is, as that header even says, and internal header and an implementation-detail of GCC. It can change at any time, it could include macros that make your code format your drives, it could just vanish with the next release.

Answer (score 2):

If your teacher is an [ICPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Collegiate_Programming_Contest) coach then he/she is right, but if your teacher is a software engineer probably he/she is not.

There are pros and cons of both:

**pros**:

- Using it saves coding time
- You don't need to take the pain of remembering which header contains what
- If you have a source code limit(which ICPC style contests generally have) and you want to squeeze in as many lines as possible then it might come handy.

**cons**:

- But it increases compile time.
- Since it includes lots of namespaces, you may accidentally get into issues which might be hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the top answer to the [Quora question mentioned by @Lightness Races in Orbit](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-good-practice-to-use-include-bits-stdc++-h-in-programming-contests-instead-of-listing-a-lot-of-includes), there's nothing wrong with including `bits/stdc++.h` in the context of a programming competition. The disadvantages around portability, compile time, and standardization are not relevant there. The same would be true in a college programming class if the example code uses that include.

If you're writing production code, then don't use it. It shouldn't be a big deal to switch back and forth depending on the purpose of the code you're currently writing.

Comment: Meh, if a programming competition is judging broken, non-standard code then I don't really get the purpose of it. "Who can make the most broken code the fastest" yay! Well done, I guess....

Comment: A one-line convenience doesn't make the whole program broken, any more than, for example, using short variable names does. I think you may be judging all of competitive programming based on a few people who show up on SO with off-topic questions about it.

Comment: Using short variable names and using `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` are _completely_ different things!

Comment: They're both examples of programming practices that make sense when submitting a contest program that has a lifetime of an hour or so, but not when writing code that needs to be maintained for years.

Comment: "The same would be true in a college programming class if the example code used that include." Heck no. The people you teach to don't know any better. They don't know what's appropriate and what's not: anything the professor writes is gospel taken on faith. Please, don't suggest any educators that this idiocy is warranted.

Comment: "Broken", "non-standard", "non-portable", "idiocy": all of these are scare words that don't belong to this discussion. Code using the include in question is no more non-portable than code that includes a third-party library. Being one of those things that can be ported trivially if and when the need arises, it is absolutely harmless and I consider it a pointlessly inflammatory gesture to be referring to hundreds of thousands of programs that use it as "broken". This discussion is a good example of what happens when standards pedantry and portability zealotry get in the way of convenience.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: There is a big difference between installing a third-party library to satisfy a dependency, and having to hack the heck out of someone else's code to make it work (thus necessarily creating a fork in the process). You accuse us of doing nothing but employing "scare words", but I challenge you to explain what you're doing here saying we're "pedants" and "zealots" with no goals further to being those things. Physician.... heal thyself.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Last I checked, any given compiler's internal header files explicitly _can't_ be ported to another compiler trivially, because they're liable to rely on compiler-specific keywords and extensions that other compilers won't necessarily support.  Therefore, to port an internal header, you have to go through the entire thing, and rewrite _anything_ that uses compiler-specific code, then rewrite all of the target compiler's files to use the new header instead of their _own_ compiler-specific internal headers.  Try porting Visual Studio's `<xlocale>` to GCC, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: `<xlocale>` will do nothing unless you rewrite GCC's `<locale>` to use it.  If you do, you'll get errors about not having files like `<xlocinfo>` or `<xdebug>`, and about not having MS's 20,000 or so internal macros defined.  ...Not exactly the most trivial of things.  ...Meanwhile, a third-party library can just be used as-is, perhaps with minor configuration necessary by defining one or two macros.  There is a _large_ difference between the two.

Comment: *"The same would be true in a college programming class"* - Certainly not. After all, it is college students that eventually write production code. What's worse, if you teach enough students the wrong thing, they will eventually wind up in teams, where no one is left that knows what's right and wrong. Convenience is nice. Convenience with as high a cost and as little a benefit is highly questionable.

Comment: @IInspectable Production code is different from college code, example code in documentation, and competitive programming code. Coding standards should be optimized for the goals of the code, not strictly applied without regard for context. A team working on a web application that deploys every day is going to use different rules than one writing code running on a robot that gets launched into space.

Comment: You haven't made a convincing point, why college students shouldn't be taught the Right Way, from the beginning. Plus, portability concerns are very real, even with college programming assignments. I remember always using Visual Studio for authoring and debugging, but had to pass in code that would compile with GCC. This is all the more true today, with a plethora of compilers and IDE's readily available.

Comment: @IInspectable College students should be taught to use the Right Way for the problem context. If they're doing competitive programming (which is the context of this question) then `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is the Right Way. That's just how it's done in that community. In other contexts, they can be taught production programming standards.

Comment: I fail to see the context you keep repeating. Nothing in the question even remotely indicates some sort of competition. And even then, I don't see the relative merit over doing it the Right Way.

Comment: @IInspectable `bits/stdc++.h` originates in the competitive programming community. See the [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-good-practice-to-use-include-bits-stdc++-h-in-programming-contests-instead-of-listing-a-lot-of-includes) linked in the top answer above. Competitive programming solutions are written once, and then thrown away once the contest is over. So the disadvantages cited above (portability, slow compilation, only works on one compiler, etc.) are not relevant.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer. I think it's a perfectly legitimate use-case to use 1 include to include them all when in a massive rush to complete a coding exercise and you don't have time to meticulously trace down the 10 specific includes you otherwise need. Production code use? No, but the answer states that too. +1.

Comment: Here is a highly-upvoted answer which supports this answer: [How does #include <bits/stdc++.h> work in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764128/4561887). And [here is the most-upvoted answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25311198/4561887), which also supports this answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Meh, if a programming competition is judging broken, non-standard code then I don't really get the purpose of it.". These competitions are merely for judging designing an algorithm and implementing them as quick as possible. It would be a foolish decision to not use compiler extensions (such as variable array sizes) and other  compiler-specific stuff (like this) if they are faster to code merely just because it's not the standard. Nobody ever said you should do the same thing in a non-competitive setting.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem for me is that including this header file won’t compile. So if it’s there, I’ll have to remove it, try to compile, and add the standard header files that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be that `bits/stdc++.h` really seems to be a internal implementation detail header of GNU libstdc++. Thus, it should never be directly included from c++ program sources.

This is based on a consistent observation that on GNU/linux, subdirectories named `bits` most likely seem to be the conventional place where the GNU libc and GNU libstdc++ put their internal private headers. Such headers contain implementation details, and their existence are not guaranteed to be stable across patch compiler versions.

Taking a look at the glibc headers directly located under `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/`, almost all of them prohibit direct inclusion by use of `#error` directives.

Similarly, for the GNU libstdc++ headers; those are located under `/usr/include/c++/12/bits/` or `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12/bits/` (almost) all of them have documentation comments at the beginning such as:

```cpp
/** @file bits/atomic_wait.h
 *  This is an internal header file, included by other library headers.
 *  Do not attempt to use it directly. @headername{atomic}
 */
```

Grepping under some `bits` subdirectories seem to indicate this directory really is reserved for the implementation. Assuming version of gcc is 12, on a x86_64 arch, try the following commands:

```bash
$ grep "Never include" /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/*.h
$ grep "Do not attempt to use it directly" /usr/include/c++/12/bits/{*.h,*.tcc}
$ grep "Do not attempt to use it directly" /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12/bits/*.h
```

Now, the header `bits/stdc++.h` is somewhat special, as it is used to generate a precompiled header for the hole library. As such, it is more of a `.cpp` implementation file rather than a proper `.h` header file -- `.cpp` source are not meant for inclusion.

Regarding the use of precompiled headers, good C++ practice is to make C++ programs/libraries that do not depend on whether a precompiled header is used to build the executable/library; simply adhere to the "Include what you use" principle. Use of a precompiled header should be specified by external means, from the build system or the command line, but not from `#include` directives in source files.

From the viewpoint of the GNU libstdc++'s API, the file `bits/stdc++.h` is not exposed as being part of it, and is only mentioned in the context of creating a binary `pch`, and only gives instructions on how to use this precompiled header from the *command line* invocation of `g++`, namely it *does not* instruct to directly include the file anywhere in source code; it is not exposed as being part of the public API of libstdc++'s header set -- in other words, it is not includeable (in essence).